# declarativeNetRequest won't redirect request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I want to make us of the `declarativeNetRequest` API to redirect users to the **youtube** homepage when they try to load **amazon.com**. When I debug my code I get no problems at all but unfortunately it is not working in the browser. Any constructive input on why that might be would be highly appreciated.

`Manifest.json` file :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Honours Project",
  "background": {
    "service": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "type": "service_worker",
      "persistent": true
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/",
    "webRequest",
    "*://amazon.com/*",
    "*://youtube.com/*",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "action": {
    "default_icon": "images/zi.png",
    "default_title": "My Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/zi.png"

  }


}
```

`Background.js` file:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.addRule({
    id: 'redirect-to-youtube',
    priority: 100,
    condition: {
      urlFilter: 'https://www.amazon.com/'
    },
    action: {
      type: 'redirect',
      redirectUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/'
    }
  }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
  
    // Update the dynamic rules to apply the new rule to all active tabs
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(function() {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
      }
  
      console.log('Successfully added declarative rule');
    });
  });
```

I added a rule to redirect my **amazon** url to the **youtube** url.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `background` section in manifest.json is incorrect. Here's how it should look:

```json
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
```

2. `host_permissions` don't match the sites. Use `"*://www.amazon.com/"`, same for youtube.
3. Rule id must be a number.
4. declarativeNetRequest API doesn't have `addRule` method.

Let's use updateDynamicRules properly:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [1],
    addRules: [{
      id: 1,
      condition: {
        urlFilter: '|https://www.amazon.com/'
      },
      action: {
        type: 'redirect',
        redirectUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/'
      }
    }],
  });
});
```

**An alternative solution is to use static rules:**

1. remove `background` section from manifest.json, remove background.js file.
2. add this to manifest.json:

   ```json
     "declarative_net_request": {
       "rule_resources" : [{
         "id": "ruleset_1",
         "enabled": true,
         "path": "rules.json"
       }]
     },
   ```
3. create rules.json:

   ```json
   [{
     "id": 1,
     "condition": {
       "urlFilter": "|https://www.amazon.com/"
     },
     "action": {
       "type": "redirect",
       "redirectUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
     }
   }]
   ```